# An unexpected output for C++ code.Can someone explain?

Tags: c++

I came across this code while doing random search and I though to execute it on www.ideone.com and the output came 0 while I was expecting it to be 10.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {


    int count = 0; 
for(int i=0; i < 10; ++i) 
 count = count++; 

std::cout << count; 
    return 0;
}
```

As far as my understanding is, `count = count++;` can be assumed as `count = count;` and `count = count + 1;` So shouldn't the output be 10 instead of 0?What is the reason for such a behaviour?

**NOTE:** As pointed out by comments here that this question comes under "Undefined Behavior and Sequence Points", I want to just make it clear that as I am new to C++, I didn't knew that these are undefined behavior.So, I hope everyone will forgive for mistake.

Comment: Have you tried count = ++count; ? (not tested) The side where the ++ is determines how the increment is asigned.

Comment: @Yelinna, That's also UB pre-C++11.

Comment: @Paranaix as I am new to C++, I didn't knew that it comes under Undefined Behavior and Sequence points. Thanks for letting me know.I will read it.

Comment: In your can try and see what the output will be when you have count++ alone instead of count= count++... then you will find the difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line that is the problem is `count = count++;`.  For a ridiculously detailed description of what is wrong, read [Undefined behavior and sequence points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points).

Basically, you come to the problem of which evaluates first, the assignment to `count` from the `=` operator or the assignment to `count` from the `++` operator.  If it evaluates the assignment from the `++` operator first, then you will get 0.  If it evaluates the `=` before the assignment from the `++`, then you will get 10.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIR this is an unspecified behaviour, the result may vary from compiler to compiler.

Comment: It is *Undefined* Behaviour, see [intro.execution]/15. But why downvote this answer?

Answer (score -1):

You can just use count++; and it will increment. count++; is equivalent to count = count + 1;

Comment: I think you didn't read the post completely.I am using count++ only.

Comment: What I meant was instead of count = count++; you should use count++; or count = count + 1;

Answer (score -1):

When you do this:

```
count = count++;
```

You have essentially created a new value for `count` at this point. The `count++` on the right is now considered an rvalue and the new value of count is the last value that was in `count++`. i.e. 0